# Remove item from arraylist using a wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove item(s) from a collection using wildcards. There are multiple elements with similar names:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array = @(
    "server1=localhost"
    "server2=127.0.0.1"
    "server3=12.13.14.15"
    "server4=192.168.1.1"
}
```

I can remove a single item using the remove method: `$Array.Remove('server1=localhost')`

Is there a way to remove an item with the wildcard character `*`? For example:

```
 $Array.Remove('server*')
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
($Array | Where-Object {$_ -like "Server*"}) | ForEach-Object {$Array.Remove($_)}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Remove` method that takes a wildcard but you can do that using the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
$Array = $Array | Where-Object {$_ -NotLike "server1*"}
```